# Could not load image of .JPG format

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I was trying to load image from local resource whose format is .JPG. But every time it gives me following error.

[image]

Do react native support .JPG format ? Can anyone help me on this ? Thanks...

Comment: you can use .jpg, i guess the path is wrong :)

Comment: the image with extension .jpg is showing with in that same folder.only the image with .JPG is not showing...

Comment: As i read in the web, the images should be with lower letters, as the xml files in Android.

Comment: React might not support .JPG format, so you can edit your picture to .png or .jpg format and try once. #cheers

Comment: @SusylGhimire thats the second choice .. it means react native don't support .JPG ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that your image_path is right then you could rename the Image in your folder from the capital letters (.JPG) to lower case letters (.jpg).

Tested this case for Windows and could reproduce and fix it with the above solution.

react-native version: 0.23.1

For clarification:

```
var yourPicture = require('./yourPathToYourPicture/picture.jpg); //Working

var yourPicture = require('./yourPathToYourPicture/picture.JPG); //Not-Working
```

> Solution to solve the capital letter problem: Save your picture in your project folder with lower case letters yourPicture.JPG -> yourPicture.jpg

Use your image

```
render(){
    return(
        <Image source={yourPicture}/>
    );
}
```

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1372695
There was a blog discussion about why you get no callback from a .JPG link - Should be the solution

Comment: I think it happens only in Linux as LInux is case sensitive.

Comment: For me its the same and i am using Windows. I wrote a jpg image with capital letters and it didn´t find the source - As far as i changed the filename in the directory to .jpg with lower case letter it worked.
- So same for Windows

Comment: but the question remains the same... react native don't support .JPG ??

Comment: Seems not to be the case. As I wrote i tested with capital letter with react-native version: 0.23.1 and it did not work - so it seems that react-native does not support capital endings for images. :) More i cannot say to this topic. To sum up -> React-Native supports .jpg -> React-Native doesn´t support .JPG
Hopefully could help u

Comment: If you're satisfied with this result, please make sure to mark it as the answer so others searching for the same problem can benefit from the solution.

Comment: Are you hell bent on using jpg or can you save it as a png? I don't know if React supports jpg.

Comment: We are talking about react-native as described above. And in this case react-native is supporting .jpg the same as .png.

Answer (score 0):

You must use `Image` from `react-native`

```
import {
  Image,
} from 'react-native';
...
```

Image have a prop called source

```
<Image source={require('./img/fotofondo_app.jpg')}/>
```

If the error still, try to execute `react-native run-android` beacuse the image files aren't read in hot.